# How to run matlab from the terminal on Ubuntu

Tags: matlab

I am trying to open matlab on Ubuntu 12.04
On typing ./matlab once I am in the folder containing matlab, I get the following message:

bash: ./matlab: Permission denied.

What could the problem be? Is it because matlab is not an executable file?

I tried running this first but it doesn't seem to have made a difference:

chmod +x /media/DATA-1/bin/matlab

(I checked the permissions tab on the file, and it doesn't let me mark 'Allow executing file as program'.)
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Show us the folder structure inside of the matlab folder.

Also do an 

    ls -all 

inside the folder so that we can see the permissions.

Comment: Have added the folder details.

Comment: It looks like you are running matlab on a mounted drive. By default linux mount drives with no-execute permission. Either copy the whole matlab directory to your home folder or remount the drive with execute permissions. To do the latter take a look at first 3 links on this google search- https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mounting+a+drive+with+execute+permissions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=i27QVI7zAZbV8gXw7oKgCg

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are running matlab on a mounted drive. By default linux mount drives with no-execute permission. That is why you are unable to mark the execute permission field.

To get around it, either copy the whole matlab directory to your home folder or remount the drive with execute permissions. To do the latter take a look at first 3 links on this google search- https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mounting+a+drive+with+execute+permissions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=i27QVI7zAZbV8gXw7oKgCg

Comment: Thanks- I copied the matlab directory into my home folder. I am still unable to run it, though. When I double click the matlab file, it gives me the option of running it in the terminal. When I select this, nothing happens. Alternately when I run the following: /bin/matlab, I get this message- No such file or directory.

Comment: I tried the following: /home/arun/bin/matlab and got this message: /home/arun/bin/matlab: 1: exec: /home/arun/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: Permission denied

Comment: @Arundhathi what are the permissions for `/home/arun/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB`

Comment: Read and write, and 'Allow executing file as program' is checked. This is the message I get when I type /home/arun/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB- /home/arun/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: error while loading shared libraries: libXm.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: If MATLAB comes with an installer for Ubuntu that ensures it can find relevant library I would go for that? Otherwise, you could hack your way around by doing `ldd matlab` and then add the paths to any missing libraries in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.